# while block doesn't loop as expected

Tags: python, loops

```
def fvals_sqrt(x):
    """
    Return f(x) and f'(x) for applying Newton to find a square root.
    """
    f = x**2 - 4.
    fp = 2.*x
    return f, fp

def solve(fvals_sqrt, x0, debug_solve = False):
    """
    Solves the sqrt function, using newtons methon.
    """
    iters = 0
    f, fp = 0.
    while  f > 10**-14 | -f < 10**-14:
        f, fp = fvals_sqrt(x0)
        x0 = x0 - (f/fp)
        iters = iters+1
        print  + " x = %22.15e in %i iterations " % (x0, iters)
        return x0, iters

    print "we're done"
```

I want this while loop once f once less than 10^-14, but i'm not sure how to modify the argument to make the loop iteratable, any help?

Comment: There is also the problem that you are initialising `f = 0.` outside of the loop

Comment: Actually, `f, fp = 0.` is a syntax error isn't it???

Comment: @wim -- I'm not sure about a syntax error, but a `TypeError` at least...

Comment: @mgilson you're definitely correct, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want logical `or` instead of `|`:

```
while  f > 10**-14 or -f < 10**-14:
```

Note that there is a difference in operator precedence between logical or (`or`) and bitwise or (`|`).  Your previous statement was likely being parsed as:

```
while (f > (10**-14 | -f)) < 10**-14):
```

which seems like it would raise a `TypeError`...

It might be easier to write:

```
while abs(f) > 10**-14:
```

Answer (score 2):

`|` operator  is used for `bitwise-OR` so you should use the logical `or` here and secondly  the `return` statement is also at wrong place and it'll end your loop only after one iteration.

```
def solve(fvals_sqrt, x0, debug_solve = False):
    iters = 0
    f, fp = 0.
    while  f > 10**-14 or -f < 10**-14:
        f, fp = fvals_sqrt(x0)
        x0 = x0 - (f/fp)
        iters = iters+1
        print  + " x = %22.15e in %i iterations " % (x0, iters)
    print "we're done"
    return x0, iters
```

Answer (score 2):

`while  f > 10**-14 | -f < 10**-14` is using the bitwise OR, not the logical OR. Use the `or` keyword:

```
while  f > 10**-14 or -f < 10**-14:
```

Also, you `return` inside of your `while` loop. You have to drop this line down one level of indentation:

```
    return x0, iters
```